# <some-valid-url>/<some-name>.m is going into infinite loop. Springboot + Mustache template + Angular

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mustache, template-engine

I have one spring boot + mustache project which is service the angular build as static resource.

It's working properly for all the urls except urls with .m extensions

For e.g. if I hit

http://localhost:8080/bank/login -- it works

http://localhost:8080/bank/login123 (invalid) -- it redirects to the /login page (i have redirection login for 404 error)

http://localhost:8080/bank/login.html(invalid) -- it redirects to the /login page

**http://localhost:8080/bank/login.m(invalid)** -- it goes into infinite loop (culprit is .m)

Any idea what's wrong with ***.m** urls

Below is the redirection logic if the url is not found

```
 @GetMapping("/error")
public ModelAndView handler404(HttpServletRequest request) {
if (statusCode != null && statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            

            return new ModelAndView("forward:/bank/login");
        } 
  }
```

The code is on corporate network so can't share much of it but if you looking for specific piece I can provide.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Who is going into infinite loop? spring?

Comment: http://localhost/bank/login.m this url ... it never loads on the page..keeps making the request

Comment: What is the backend sending to the frontend when you access that url?. I mean this could be anything, are you processing the url in spring? Do you have an error handling in the front end? Because your backend could be sending a different error for this specific case and the frontend is processing that error in a different way than the other ones.

Comment: That may be the case. Frontend is actually an angular build which have js/css and other static resources.. let me analyze that.. will post my findings here

Comment: @MissingSemiColon thank you for the suggestion . It was the angular code that had special handling for *.m urls, after removing it worked like charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to hear that.